# Exception in delivering result of invoking 'isFbExists': RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: exception, meteor

Help me with this error

my template and `isFbExists` methods are like below

**My template:**

```
{{#each friendsPolls.data}}
    {{#if username}}
         {{#each questions}} 
            {{question}}
         {{/each}} 
    {{/if}}
    <br>    
 {{/each}}
```

**My helpers**

```
Template.fb.helpers({
    friendsPolls: function () {
        Meteor.call('getFriendsData', function(err, data2) { 

                Session.set("fbfdata", data2);

            });
    return Session.get("fbfdata");
    },
    questions:function(){
        //console.log(this.username);
        Meteor.call('isFbExists', this.username, function (error, result) {
            if(result)
            {
                console.log(result._id);
                var fbfq= Ques_Coll.find({owner:result._id});
                Session.set("fbFriendsQues", fbfq);
            }
        });
        //return Session.get("fbFriendsQues");
    }
});
```

**my server methods**

```
isFbExists:function(arg1){
            var efg=Meteor.users.findOne({"services.facebook.username":arg1},{fields: {'_id': 1}});

        return efg;


        }
```

What's problem with my code.

I don't even know what that error means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I don't know much about this error,But i solved this few days back

In my program some `infinite loop` has happened and i edited that then it works fine.

In your case

```
{{#each friendsPolls.data}}
    {{#if username}}
         {{#each questions}} 
            {{question}}
         {{/each}} 
    {{/if}}
    <br>    
 {{/each}}
```

In this code,some `infinite loop` may be going on please check it

Once again,this may not be the solution to your problem,but check it once

Comment: Yeah, i checked it by logging results it is looping